# How can I tell on what page a user entered the application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 application, and it consists of a main site and a series of branded subdomain sites. I need to find out how to check what a user's entry point so that I can decide when to put a link back to the main site.

How can I tell in Rails where someone entered the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to share session across subdomains. I assume that you control all subdomains entirely then it will be secure as app with no subdomains.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store,  
                                   :key => '_app_session',  
                                   :domain => '.mydomain.com'
```

Then on first entry remember the first subdomain name in session variable using filter.

```
session[:entry_host] ||= request.host
```

Link back should then look like

```
if session[:entry_host]
  link 'Home', root_url(:host => session[:entry_host])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store this information in session:

In you application_controller:

```
before_filter :check_entry_point

def entry_point
  # the ||= will let the first entry point alive
  session[:entry_point] ||= params[:controller] + params[:action]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro. It is actually going to help me on something else I'm working on.